# clojure pmap/preduce vs fork-join

Tags: concurrency, clojure

Looks like clojure [will have a fork-join implementation](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/par/src/clj/clojure/par.clj) which looks like a functional wrapper over java's fork join framework.

I am wondering what the difference between these and pmap/preduce could be ?

Comment: This is going to be a topic of a talk at the Clojure-conj conference: http://clojure-conj.org/speakers#liebke  David liebke is now actively working on it for the next version of clojure

Comment: @Alex that abstract is what prompted this question :).

Comment: Is any thought being given to an implementation strategy for fork-join on ClojureCLR or generally ensuring the fork-join API is friendly to alternative implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fork-join is more general than the sequence-based `pmap`/`preduce`, and should allow for more fine-grained control over parallelism.  The exact APIs for doing this are still up in the air.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at that code, their functionality will be mostly the same - the only difference is that `pmap` uses Futures running on the Agent threadpool as it's underlying primitive, while `pvmap` uses fork-join.

I'm not in a position to say for sure, but I'd expect that whichever one performs better in the general case would become the standard implementation for `pmap`, unless there are significant enough tradeoffs to make having both worthwhile.

It also looks like (for now at least) the fork-join framework only supports vectors, so it's not semi-lazy like `pmap`.

Answer (score 2):

These slides contain some charts showing comparisons between the two approaches: http://data-sorcery.org/2010/10/23/clojureconj/

Answer (score 1):

One difference, as far as I understand it, is that `pmap` will run only at whatever degree of "chunkiness" it is given. The function is mapped over each member of the sequence given to `pmap`. If a the granularity is too small the potential benefits of parallelism get swallowed in the overhead of creating and managing too many `Future`s.

Fork-join enables work stealing so that how much gets run on each thread can be adaptive.

Answer (score 1):

Neither pmap or pvmap will save us from having to use **the correct chunk size**. For my projects that usually means breaking the data into chunks and using map on each chunk, then using pmap to map the chunks in parallel. then reduce and flatten.